# Creating a list assigned to each class instance

Tags: python, class, passwords

Hey so I have trying to get into programming for the past week so with that in mind, please show my code some mercy.

I have little idea of what i am actually doing but i guess I am trying to create an employee class that has a password function  which creates a random password per employee instance. My problem is I do not know on how to go about creating a password string per employee instance. I have tried creating a "passw" list but this simply duplicated the random password.

Here is my code:

```
import random
import string
alpha = (string.ascii_letters)

class employee:
    def __init__(self, name, passw):
        self.n = name
        self.pa =passw
        passw= []

    def password(self,name,diff):
        if name == self.n:
            print("successs")

        else:
            print("none found")

        if diff == 1:
            for i in range(5):
                passw.append((random.choice(alpha)))
        elif diff == 2:
            for i in range(7):
                passw.append((random.choice(alpha)))
        elif diff == 3:
            for i in range(10):
                passw.append((random.choice(alpha)))    

        else:
            return("please select an appropirate difficulty")

        return "".join(passw)


akki = employee("akki",passw)
akki.password("akki",2)

jane= employee("jane",passw)
jane.password("jane",2)
```

as output I get:

```
successs
successs
'fChfnJixtmLmPmAKxOThSGqYXjJpCeEUhEwG'
```

Any thoughts on how to go about creating a password per employee?

Comment: What is the need for the passw argument of __init__()? And why is 'name' an argument of the password function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new password for each employee just include some code in the **init**() function that creates a random string and assigns it to an attribute of the class.

When you need to access the password, just access the password attribute of that class instance ie.

```
class employee():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pwd = ''.join([random.choice(alpha) for i in range(10)])


jane = employee('jane')
print(jane.pwd)
```